# I need an example on how to use the function create created by the RESTful from entity class

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I need an example on how to use the function create created by the RESTful from entity class

My entity class (Countries) :

package entities;

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;


/**
 *
 * @author oracle
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "COUNTRIES")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Countries.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Countries c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Countries.findByCountryId", query = "SELECT c FROM Countries c WHERE c.countryId = :countryId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Countries.findByCountryName", query = "SELECT c FROM Countries c WHERE c.countryName = :countryName")})
public class Countries implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 2)
    @Column(name = "COUNTRY_ID")
    private String countryId;
    @Size(max = 40)
    @Column(name = "COUNTRY_NAME")
    private String countryName;

  static SessionFactory sessionFactory ;


    public Countries() {
    }

    public Countries(String countryId) {
        this.countryId = countryId;
    }

    public String getCountryId() {
        return countryId;
    }

    public void setCountryId(String countryId) {
        this.countryId = countryId;
    }

    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }

    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (countryId != null ? countryId.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Countries)) {
            return false;
        }
        Countries other = (Countries) object;
        if ((this.countryId == null && other.countryId != null) || (this.countryId != null && !this.countryId.equals(other.countryId))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entities.Countries[ countryId=" + countryId + " ]";
    }
```

My CountriesFacadeREST contains the create function :

```
 @POST
    @Override
    @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public void create(Countries entity) {
        super.create(entity);

    }
```

the client code is from an android application :

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();



    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.104:8080/wsDatabase/webresources/entities.countries/create");
String text = null;
try {
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);


HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();


text = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);


} catch (Exception e) {
return e.getLocalizedMessage();
}

return text;
}
```

BTW : the client code is working and tested on other web services but I need to let it work on a "create web service "

Comment: Can I know please why I got a "-1"

Comment: I would guess the -1 comes from the fact that the question boils down to a "please write some code for me". A better question probably would have been formulated like "Here is my attempt to use the RESTful functions from this code. I expected it to do X but it did Y instead. Please help me understand why."

Comment: So we should do English courses before writing any questions :/

Comment: Not really. We have plenty of questions by non-native English speakers; poor grammar is cleaned up relatively quickly. What is frowned upon is a request for other users to write you code; that is not the purpose of StackOverflow. A good question attempts to solve the problem, and then asks specific questions about what may have gone wrong in the attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your HttpGet with HttpPost since your rest service answer to a POST request.

Comment: I'm sry JFPicard I copied this code that works with HttpGet ... I will fix my question now ...